# Does FME remember processes that have run?

Tags: modelbuilder, fme-form

Just getting into FME after being used to ArcMAP Modelbuilder.

Every process in the model in FME is run everytime you press run. In ArcGIS Model builder it remembers the processes run and only runs the processes required to get to the step you are in that have not been run. This only resets if the inputs change or if you reset the model inputs.

Can FME do the same? I want to use it in research so I am building my process as I go on a large dataset so I don't want to waste time to re-run processes that I know work correctly.

Comment: i think you have to do it using several workspaces with workspace runner

Comment: No, FME will run the entire dataset each time.  However, you can speed things up by limiting the number of features that are read.  Each reader has a maximum features to be read (or something like that) parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can judge the existence of the result dataset and only when the dataset does not exist for processing. You can use FileExistenceChecker and NoFeaturesTester, they can from the [FME HUB](https://hub.safe.com/) for download. Will you want to undertake the processing of connected to NoFeatruesTester NOINPUT port will be able to achieve your goal. [image]

Comment: Interesting but what if the output is temporary? it seems a bit of extra work to have to do this when there should be a flag withing fme which tells it if something has been run or not like in arcmap